# angularjs ng-repeat dependable selectBox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, combobox, ng-options

i want to make my selectbox dependable, so, if i choose region "America", the second selectBox should only show New York, but i don't have any idea how to make it, i try to use ng-click inside my option, but it doesn't work. And i can't change my database type, i need to work with it, so anyone know how to make it without change any database structure?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
  
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.countryList=[];
 $scope.data =[
 {id:1, country_code:"KR", country_name:"Korea", city_name:"Busan", city_code:"PUS"},
 {id:1, country_code:"KR", country_name:"Korea", city_name:"Seoul", city_code:"SEL"},
 {id:1, country_code:"KR", country_name:"Korea", city_name:"Ulsan", city_code:"USN"},
 {id:1, country_code:"KR", country_name:"Korea", city_name:"GwangJu", city_code:"KWJ"},
 {id:1, country_code:"KR", country_name:"Korea", city_name:"Gunsan", city_code:"KUV"},
 {id:1, country_code:"USA", country_name:"America", city_name:"New York", city_code:"NY"}
 ];
  
  
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
     var isExist = false;
     for (var j = 0; j < $scope.countryList.length; j++) {
      if (JSON.stringify($scope.data[i].country_code) == JSON.stringify($scope.countryList[j].country_code)) {
       isExist = true;
       break;
      }
     }
     if (isExist == false) {
      $scope.countryList.push($scope.data[i]);
     }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class="port_small_select_div">
            <select class="small_select">
              <option disabled selected hidden>Region</option>
              <option ng-repeat="country in countryList" value="{{ country.country_code }}">{{ country.country_name}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="port_select_div">
            <select class="big_select">
              <option disabled selected hidden>Detailed information</option>
              <option ng-repeat="city in data" value="{{ city.city_code }}">{{ city.city_name}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply filter over the second dropdown based on `country_code` of selection of 1st dropdown. I also replaces dropdown to use `ng-options`. Also you should consider adding `ng-model` to each select box.

```
<select class="small_select" ng-model="selectedRegion" 
  ng-options="country.country_name as country_code for in countryList">
  <option disabled selected hidden>Region</option>
</select>

<select class="big_select" ng-model="selectedCity"
 ng-options="city.city_code as city.city_name for city in data | filter: {country_code: selectedRegion }">
  <option disabled selected hidden>Detailed information</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how to make it without using ng-option?
is it possible?

Comment: Ah i got it, but the problem is, this "<option disabled selected hidden>Region</option>" wont show anymore, why and how to show it? Thanks!